# bootstrap md and sm cause overflow of text in <p> tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i have the following code which causes the text to spill over the div.

If i resize of lg or xs its fine, it restructures the sentence to fit

```
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0"> 
        <div class="thumbnail">
                <div>
                    <p>
                        This sentence is overspilling the border oft eh div and causing me some problems that i wish it didnt. It does not do this for sm, xs or lg
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        All icing figures, bespoke cake shaping and decoration are charged additionally and are dependent on individual requirements and the time taken to make.
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Note, if all the sizes above `xs` are the same size - size of 8 and offset of 2 - you only need to use `sm`, so `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">` and not `md and lg`. Also, `col-*-offset-0` isn't a class in Bootstrap, as offsetting by 0 columns isn't offsetting at all.

Comment: ok thanks but that doesnt answer my question. Why is it happening?

Comment: I'm well aware that doesn't answer your question... I posted it as a comment. I don't know what - and therefore why - whatever you're describing is happening.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaGXQm Looking good

Comment: You're correct Tim, apologies.

makshh, i went to the link but its the blank home page, did you want to point to something or want me to try to insert code here?

Comment: I updated the comment. It works now.

Comment: Ok it think got the issue - i have it surrounded by a "container" and you have just "thumbnail" ...more investigation needed...

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it all in 2 more divs like this:

```
<section id="something">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0"> 
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div>
                    <p>
                        This sentence is overspilling the border oft eh div and causing me some problems that i wish it didnt. It does not do this for sm, xs or lg
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        All icing figures, bespoke cake shaping and decoration are charged additionally and are dependent on individual requirements and the time taken to make.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end container -->
</section>
```